# Python - How to convert HTML entity to UTF-8

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I want to convert in Python 2.7 string like 
`"&#128;", "&#380;"`
and similar to UTF-8 string. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

## Python3

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('&copy;')
'©'
>>> html.unescape('&#128;')
'€'
>>> html.unescape('&#380;')
'ż'
```

It's in `html` module in python.